# MYSQL subquery needs to return multiple rows with LIMIT 5 per result from the parent query

Tags: mysql, subquery, limit

I have three tables for my NFL database

**Players** - which has player id/name

**stats_passing** - which has player id, game_id, yards and touchdowns by game

**Game** - which has game date

I'm trying to get the top four players with the most yards and touchdowns in the last five games they've played in.

I have this so far:

```
SELECT
    p.name,
    SUM(s.yds) AS tot_yds,
    SUM(s.tds) AS tot_tds
FROM players AS p
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        s.id,
        s.player_id,
        s.yds,
        s.tds
    FROM stats_passing AS s
    INNER JOIN games AS g ON s.game_id = g.id
    WHERE YEAR(g.date) = 2014
    ORDER BY s.player_id, g.date DESC
    LIMIT 5) AS s ON p.id = s.player_id
ORDER BY tot_yds DESC, tot_tds DESC
LIMIT 4
```

However it's only returning one result.

```
Drew Brees, 1497, 10
```

But as I said above, I want the top four players sorted by their total yards and total touchdowns similar to

```
Drew Brees, 1497, 10
Tom Brady, 1234, 9
Andrew Luck, 1123, 8
Aaron Rodgers, 1023, 7
```

I've been working on this for days and I think my mysql knowledge is at its end.  Please help!  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  Hope this helps someone else.  Feel free to add to it if it's inefficient.

```
SET @rn = 0;
SET @prev = 0;

SELECT
    name,
    tot_yds,
    tot_tds
FROM (
    SELECT
        p.name,
        SUM(s.yds) AS tot_yds,
        SUM(s.tds) AS tot_tds
    FROM players AS p
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            s.id,
            s.player_id,
            s.yds,
            s.tds,
            @rn := CASE WHEN @prev = s.player_id
                    THEN @rn + 1
                    ELSE 1
                   END AS rn,
            @prev := s.player_id
        FROM (SELECT
                st.id,
                st.player_id,
                st.yds,
                st.tds
             FROM stats_passing AS st
             INNER JOIN games AS g ON st.game_id = g.id
              WHERE YEAR(g.date) = 2014
            ORDER BY st.player_id, g.date DESC) AS s
        ) AS s ON p.id = s.player_id 
     WHERE rn <= 5
     GROUP BY p.name) AS ns
 ORDER BY tot_yds DESC, tot_tds DESC
 LIMIT 4
```